# How to stack items above each other with flex box?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I just googled a lot and was not able to find a solution for this. I want 2 items to be centered horizontally and vertically. The trick here is that I want to stack them above each other, no problem with position:absolute, but I can't center the elements with an absolute position. I think that this should work anyhow with flexbox. With stacking I mean so that one element is hiding the other partially.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The container can be set `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center` for horizontal and vertical centering.

```css
.outer {
  align-items: center;
  background: #800000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 5px solid #353535;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}
.inner {
  background: #C83737;
  border: 5px solid #353535;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this?
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dieguezz/1qq5etad/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    align-content: center;
}

.item {
    flex: 1 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry I think you  get my question wrong or I didn't male clear what I want I gonna edit this for all.

Answer (score 1):

[this](http://jsfiddle.net/grLww5we/1/)

```
    <div class='item1'>
        <div class='item2'></div>
    </div>


    html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    display: flex;
    flex:1 1 auto;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center
}

.item1 {
    display: flex;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items:center
}    


.item2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}
```